# Moving sum by date (MS Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Table A where there are many entries for the same **CODNEG** and **Date**:

```
CODNEG  QUATOT  VOLTOT        Date
ABCD11     937  103070  31/01/2011
ABCD11    1976  205504  31/01/2011
ABCD11    1859  193336  31/01/2011
ABCD11    1026  110808  28/02/2011
ABCD11      49    4410  31/07/2011
XYZW11      35    3570  31/01/2011
XYZW11     627   63954  31/01/2011
     .       .       .           .
     .       .       .           .
     .       .       .           .
```

I'm trying to create a Query with a Field where the values are: (SUM of **VOLTOT**) / (SUM of **QUATOT**) for the same **CODNEG** from the **past twelve months**, for example, if **Date** is 31/07/2011, i'd like to SUM values from Aug/2010 to Jul/2011.

- (1) **Date** is always the last day of the month
- (2) The number of entries from the past twelve months can be any integer from 0 to ~250

I've found some similar questions, but I couldn't solve this problem based on their solutions, because the particularity number (2) makes it different.
I'd like to know if it is possible to do what i'm trying to do and if it is, how can I do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a correlated subquery.  Based on your date arithmetic, I think this would be:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(a2.voltot) / sum(a2.quatot)
        from a a2
        where a2.codneg = a.codneg and
              a2.date > dateadd("m", -12, date) and
              a2.date <= date
       ) as ratio
from a;
```

It might be a little more complicated if you actually want full months, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Note - Renamed field `Date` to `DT`

```
SELECT CODNEG, SUM(VOLTOT)/SUM(QUATOT ) AS Div, DT 
FROM (SELECT *
from tableA
Where DT Between  DateSerial(Year(DT), Month(DT)-11, 1) And DateSerial(Year(DT), Month(DT)+1, 0))  AS T
GROUP BY CODNEG, DT ;
```

**Result:**  (Input Date - `07/31/2011`)

[image]

Comment: Add `DT` column in both `Select CODNEG , DT` and  `Group By CODNEG, DT`

Comment: I think I was mistaken. When I Put `DT` column in both `Select CODNEG, DT` and `Group By CODNEG, DT` it still prompts for an input date, so I tried `DT` instead of `[Enter Date]`and i got an output which i believed that was what i'm looking for. However, I just realized that when I did this change, it calculated `Div`using all values with the same `CODNEG` and `DT` (because of the `Group By`). I don't know if I was able to explain what i'm trying to do. My desired output would be like the one from your solution, but for all dates in Table A. Is it possible?

Comment: I mean, instead of a input date (`Enter date`), I'd like to calculate `Div` using the values from the past twelve months from the `DT`, so each row in output would be something like this (CODNEG, QUATOT, VOLTOT, DT, Div): `ABCD11   937   103070   31/01/2011 
  [DT value using this date]`

Comment: Ok, give me sometime.

Comment: I have updated answer, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried this, and i realized that `DT Between  DateSerial(Year(DT), Month(DT)-11, 1) And DateSerial(Year(DT), Month(DT)+1, 0))` is always True, so the `WHERE` clause isn't filtering anything. It's calculating the SUM using all the rows with the same `CODNEG` and `DT` because of the `Group By` statement.