# MS ACCESS. Query. SUM Moving 3 Month Quantity

Tags: ms-access-2016

[image]Simplified Table Data

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 31-May-2022 | 2 |
| 30-Jun-2022 | 4 |
| 31-Jul-2022 | 8 |
| 31-Aug-2022 | 3 |
| 30-Sep-2022 | 2 |

Need a query to produce result as

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 31-Jul-2022 | 14 |
| 31-Aug-2022 | 15 |
| 30-Sep-2022 | 13 |

Column A may not be continuous. E.g. 31-Aug-2022 may be missing due to no Column B data. But moving **3 month** SUM still persists. Then 30-SEP-2022 result will be 10.

Actually in my table, Column A is a numeric. It is a month offset number. E.g. 30-Jun-2023 is -1, 31-May-2023 is -2 and so on. So 31-May-2022 is -13. This information may simplify the query.

I tried the solution here [Moving sum by date (MS Access SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444774/moving-sum-by-date-ms-access-sql)
Unsuccessful.

```
SELECT
    AC_TYPE1,
    CHAPTER,
    SUM( CountOfDEFECT_DESCRIPTION ) AS S,
    MonthCALOffSet 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            qB13_1
        WHERE
            MonthCALOffSet BETWEEN MonthCALOffSet AND MonthCALOffSet - 2 
    )
GROUP BY
    AC_TYPE1,
    CHAPTER,
    MonthCALOffSet;
```

Appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Question: is the date important? or taking care of the month & year is enough?

Comment: Please edit your sample data and SQL so that they match each other (data + column names), thanks!

Comment: @Raptor Taking care of month & year is enough. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

A simplified example of your task (moving sum by date):
Test table (tbTest)

| Id | qty | moffset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | -8 |
| 2 | 5 | -7 |
| 3 | 4 | -6 |
| 4 | 7 | -5 |
| 5 | 8 | -4 |
| 6 | 3 | -3 |
| 7 | 6 | -1 |

For test, data with moffset -2 is excluded.

Query:
1)Self join table on condition offset between current and current-2
2)Group

```
select id,sum(qty2) as qty 
FROM(
  SELECT tbTest.Id as Id, tbTest.qty as qty,tbTest.moffset as moffset
      , tbTest_1.Id as Id2, tbTest_1.qty as qty2,tbTest_1.moffset as moffset2
  FROM tbTest AS tbTest_1 LEFT JOIN tbTest 
    ON (tbTest_1.moffset>=(tbTest.moffset-2)) 
      AND (tbTest_1.moffset<=(tbTest.moffset))
)
group by id;
```

Query result

| id | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 19 |
| 6 | 18 |
| 7 | 9 |

Another example with dates

Test data

| Id | EventDate | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2023 | 3 |
| 2 | 01.02.2023 | 4 |
| 3 | 01.03.2023 | 2 |
| 4 | 01.05.2023 | 5 |
| 5 | 01.08.2023 | 8 |

Query

```
select id,sum(qty2) as qty FROM(
SELECT tbTestDate.Id as Id, tbTestDate.qty as qty,tbTestDate.EventDate as EventDate
  ,tbTestDate_1.Id as Id2, tbTestDate_1.qty as qty2,tbTestDate_1.EventDate as EventDate2
FROM tbTestDate AS tbTestDate_1 LEFT JOIN tbTestDate 
  ON (datediff("m",tbTestDate_1.EventDate,tbTestDate.EventDate)<=2) 
 AND (datediff("m",tbTestDate_1.EventDate,tbTestDate.EventDate)>=0)
)
group by id;
```

Result

| id | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

In your pic there more columns `AC_TYPE`, CHAPTER. Include to ON clause sach as `table.AC_TYPE=table1.AC_TYPE` ...

Upd1. See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/-DYZCbth)

Result on your data

| T | C | M | MY | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 737-8 | 27 | -14 | null | 20 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -13 | null | 32 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -12 | null | 38 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -11 | null | 37 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -10 | null | 30 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -9 | null | 28 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -8 | null | 16 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -7 | null | 30 |
| 737-8 | 27 | -6 | null | 40 |

Comment: (T_1.MonthCALOffset>=(T.MonthCALOffset - 2)) AND (T_1.MonthCALOffset<=(T.MonthCALOffset-2))`` condition take only 1 month (T.MonthCALOffset ``- 2``).  Should be ``(T_1.MonthCALOffset>=(T.MonthCALOffset - 2)) AND (T_1.MonthCALOffset<=(T.MonthCALOffset-2))`` condition take only 1 month (T.MonthCALOffset )

Comment: Some corrected.(T_1.MonthCALOffset>=(T.MonthCALOffset - 2)) AND (T_1.MonthCALOffset<=(T.MonthCALOffset-2))`` condition take only 1 month (T.MonthCALOffset - 2). Should be (T_1.MonthCALOffset>=(T.MonthCALOffset - 2)) AND (T_1.MonthCALOffset<=(T.MonthCALOffset))